# Selecting a range of rows that is the same number as a predefined range

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to produce a scatter graph and histogram.

I have saved the range of my active selection in a variable like so,

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Selection
```

What I'm now trying to do is select another range that is 4 columns to the left of this range - but has the same number of cells. Again, this could be saved into a variable. - If I were to do this with a single cell I would use Active.Offset - is there a similar way to do this with a range?

What I then want to do is produce the scatter graph using these two ranges as the x and y values.

For example,

```
Range(MyRange, NewRange(this will be the rows, 4 columns adjacent to MyRange)).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Addchart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = x1XYScatter
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Dim r as Range, x as Range, y as Range
Set r = Selection
Set x = r.Offset(0,4)  `same size as r, but 4 columns to the right
Set y = r.Resize(r.Rows.Count,4)  `same rows as r, but with 4 columns
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. One final question, this keeps confusing me - for example I'm using a variable (already defined as a range) in something that usually selects a range, for example the below requires X and Y values, do I do it as such,
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:= Range.(MyRange, NewRange) or do I now scrap the Range at the beginning since it's already defined as a range?
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes keep it simple. You can do something like `Source := MyRange.Resize(MyRange.Rows.Count,4)` directly so you don't have to define separately `NewRange`. Also the statement `Range(x,y)` is not needed.